# How to disable show prompt on jquery validation engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I don't want to show the Error prompt everytime i lost focus on input element, instead i just want to highlight the element without showing the prompt.  Is that possible with jquery validation engine ?

Answer (score 0):

apparently i found that there is an option to add custom prompt class, and i'm using it to add the hidden class.

```
 addPromptClass:"hidden"
```

also to highlight the input field i use this option

```
addFailureCssClassToField:"inputError"
```